# Equivalent of build() with two existing objects

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there an equivalent to the `collection.build` command in Ruby on Rails that builds a relationship between two already existing model objects? For instance, if I have a User model and a Contact model (connected both ways by a has_many_and_belongs_to) and I want to add a user to Contact's collection of users and a contact to the user's collection of contacts, is there any easy method that simply builds this connection for me? Or do I have to write out

```
    contact.users << some_user
    contact.save
    some_user.contacts << contact
    some_user.save
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that:

```
contact.users << some_user
```

is enough.

According to the Rails [Guide to Active Record Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has_and_belongs_to_many-association-reference):

> The collection << method adds one or more objects to the collection by creating records in the join table.

Comment: Is it required to save the record after appending to that collection?

Comment: Saving either of the models being joined together has no impact on the rows in the join table, so no. But I'd recommend just trying it in the console so you get a feel for it.